# Infinitesimal vs zero probabilities in uniform continuous distributions

Tags: probability

Suppose we select two numbers uniformly from $\mathbb{R}$: $x \in [0, a]$ and $y \in [0,b]$, where $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary nonnegative integers.

I can visualize this as a 2-d rectangle with side lengths $a$ and $b$. Any randomly selected point will fall within or on the boundaries of the rectangle. This lets me answer a question like "What is $P(x < y)$?" by computing an area (in this case, the area under the main diagonal, which is $\frac{1}{2}$ .)

Now if I was to try to answer "What is $P(x=y)$?" that *is* the main diagonal, and as a line, this has zero area, so $P(x=y)$ should be zero.

Is this answer actually correct, or is my way of solving the problem wrong? I know that the probability of picking a specific point in a univariate continuous distribution is 0 and only intervals have nonzero probability, but is $P(x=y)$ exactly equal to 0 or is it some infinitesimally small nonzero quantity?

Comment: Your $1/2$ is correct only when $a=b$, I believe.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes. If $X\sim\mathcal U[0;a]$ and independently $Y\sim\mathcal U[0;b]$ then: $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X\!<\!Y) ~=&~ \begin{cases}\frac{a}{2b} & : a< b \\[1ex] \tfrac 1 2 & : a=b \\[1ex] \frac{2a-b}{2a} & : a> b \end{cases}& \because \text{geometry}\\[2ex] \mathsf P(X\!=\!Y)~=&~ 0\end{align}$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp i put 1/2 because the main diagonal of a rectangle always forms a right triangle with sides $a$ and $b$ with area $\frac{ab}{2}$. So the probability is $\frac{ab}{2} * \frac{1}{ab} = \frac{1}{2}$. Where did you get the other formulas?

Comment: @contains-digits Sketch a diagram; the support is the *rectangle* with sides of lengths $a, b,$ and area $ab$. $~$ When $a<b$ the area of the event $\{X<Y\}$ is a right triangle with hypotenuse at angle $\pi/4$ from the sides, with area $a^2/2$.  When $a>b$ the area is a trapezoid; and the *complementary* event, $\{X>Y\}$, is a rectangle with area $b^2/2$.

Comment: The triangle of area $ab/2$ matches the event $\{bX<aY\}$, that is the area under the diagonal of the rectangle.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I sketched it and what you said makes sense now. I had forgotten that when x>y or vice versa, the new "acceptable area" is bounded by the size of the smaller side.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct. First off, if a probability is defined to be a real number in $[0,1]$, then a probability can't be an "infinitesimal but nonzero quantity," as such do not exist in $\Bbb{R}$ by the Archimean property.

The formation of measure theory was partially motivated by problems in probability. Given a set $S\subset [0,a]\times[0,b]$, the probability that a uniformly chosen random variable lies in $S$ is equal to the Lebesgue measure of $S$ divided by $ab$. The Lebesgue measure is, essentially, the best formal definition for the area/volume/etc. of a subset of $\Bbb{R}^n$ (well, not all subsets; there are some "unmeasureable subsets" of $\Bbb{R}^n$). The Lebesgue measure of a line in $\Bbb{R}^2$ is zero.

Comment: Just to nitpick the nitpick: The [fat Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) is an example of a subset of $[0,1]$ which contains no intervals but has positive measure/probability.

Comment: So is the intersection of $[0,1]$ with the irrationals.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the diagonal contains uncountably many points, it still has measure $0$, and therefore the probability of a point being on it is $0$. It may be that this would be different in non-standard analysis, where numbers exist that are larger than $0$ but smaller than any positive real.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of looking at it.

Consider the $n$ squares $[{k \over n} ,({k \over n}+{1 \over n }) a] \times [{k \over n}, ({k \over n}+{1 \over n}) b]$, with $k=0,...,n-1$.

Then you can see that $\Delta=\{(x,y) | x=y \}$ is contained in these squares fro any $n$, and the
total volume of the squares is ${1 \over n} ab$.

Hence the volume of $\Delta$ is zero.